# How to apply collaborative filtering on no-rating system like Twitter, Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I'm studying Collaborative Filtering and want to apply to some social network like Twitter or Facebook. I tried with some demo provided by MovieLens and understood that user has to rate on some items which reflect the interesting, and the rating will be used as input for recommend algorithms. However with some social network which there are no rating feature like Twitter or Facebook, how can I apply these algorithms.

Someone worked on this area, please give me suggestions for that.

Answer (score 4):

The keywords you should use in search are "implicit feedback". Luckily there are some good systems/approaches out there that allow you to work with such type of data.

Here is the one I consider the best https://github.com/benfred/implicit And what's even better this GitHub page provides you with links to the articles explaining the theory behind each of the approaches it uses. There are also a couple of tutorials that would help you to write your first recommender system in no time. And it's incredibly fast, took me 2 hours on quad-core PC to calculate recommendations for 600K users basing on 40M entries.

Comment: Hi @Dienow, by any chance have you come up with a good way of evaluating this implicit library? Specifically for the ALS model. Any advice would be much appreciated. Documentation is very light.

Comment: @SCool you mean evaluating on a test dataset? Some of the tutorials on github page explain how to do this (though I must admit some of these tutorials use deprecated API). I also used it on production and even implemented real-time recommendations on top of it. It beats the simple top, but I haven't had a chance to a/b test it against some other recommendations library.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using explicit ratings. You can infer implicit ratings by defining your own weights for actions like:

```
Twitter:  Reteweet=1, Save=2, Both=3
Facebook: Like=1, Share=2, Both=3
```

Using this method, you maintained a `1-3` rating system that can be fed into the collaborative-filtering algorithm.